# Ошибка при установке модуля vedis в Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

При попытке установить `vedis`, python выдает такую ошибку:

```
Collecting vedis
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/85/9a2c7907199552bb65df944e7128aa7e2018fb3e77e7ad522c74c24137b8/vedis-0.7.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\users\olexij\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from vedis) (0.29)
Installing collected packages: vedis
  Running setup.py install for vedis: started
    Running setup.py install for vedis: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Users\Olexij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Olexij\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\vedis\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Olexij\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vmgyfm6e\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'vedis' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    D:\VS IDE\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Olexij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include -IC:\Users\Olexij\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include "-ID:\VS IDE\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" /Tcvedis.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\vedis.obj
    vedis.c
    c:\users\olexij\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: ЌҐ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм д ©« ўЄ«озҐ­ЁҐ: io.h: No such file or directory,
    error: command 'D:\\VS IDE\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Искал решение этой проблемы, но нашел только то, что когда такие ошибки, то модуль можно установить только через `wheel`. Но на модуль `vedis` я не нашел колесо.
Есть ли решение этой проблемы? Если да, то какое? Если всё же существует колесо для `vedis`, то можете скинуть его?

Answer (score 1):

У меня была такая же ошибка. Нужно было апгрейднуть Microsoft Visual C++ до 14.0

Comment: Обновил, не помогло.